# Track additional parameter for click events

Tags: google-analytics

I'm pretty new to GA administration. I created an account and connected it to my website using a google tag (gtag/js?id=G-...)

Now I can see clicks on my website in the events analysis (see the screenshot). But how I can set it up to actually gather the name of the link/buttons people are clicking on? I want to know which links/buttons people click the most, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are implementing your Google Instance.

If you are using Google Tag Manager, you can pass along variables with your event. These can be both user based parameters and event based parameters. Google Tag Manager has some out of the box variables such as link URL and link text that could be sent along with the click events.

If you are just doing a normal instance of Google Analytics, you will need to pass along the data in the form of key value pairs probably using an `onclick()` function.

Regardless of how you are implementing your analytics, once you start sending the parameters along with the event, you will need to create the custom dimensions in the ain section of Google Analytics.

This will allow you to use the parameters in your reports and within visualizations built in Looker Studio.